the maximum number of documents in an elasticsearch index and difference about stats and count
I have an index in elasticsearch with only 1 primary shards e 0 replica.
When I do GET /index/_count, the result is 100,815.
When I do GET /index/_stats, the result is 64,893,983.
Each doc has nested fields.
My question is: what number do I have to consider for the limit Number of documents in the index can't exceed [2147483519]?
In case of the second one number, do you suggest to increase the number of primary shards? I have only one pc.
Thank you

Indeed, /index/_count returns the number of top-level index documents, while /index/_stats returns the number of Lucene documents, i.e. including nested ones.
The 2B limit concerns the Lucene documents, so whatever is returned by /index/_stats.
If you think you'll hit that limit, you can solve this by adding more primary shards. The fact that you have a single node on your PC doesn't change anything, it's just that you can't have replicas, but it doesn't prevent you
from having several primaries for your index.
Another solution if your data is append-only is to use a data stream that rolls over automatically after a certain number of days or number of docs or shard size.

Thank you for you answer. There is a calculation about how many shards I have to include? Because I have 70kk docs in one day each day.

I've updated my answer with another possible option
